# Jquery - hide/show based on checkbox value

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hi I have the following Form:

```
               {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'profile', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
                        <div class="checkbox-custom fill checkbox-success mb5">
                            <fieldset class="arma2-mysql-question">
                                {{ Form::checkbox('arma2-mysql', '', $user->arma2_mysql, ['id' => 'arma2-mysql', 'onChange' => 'valueChanged()']) }}
                                {{ Form::label('arma2-mysql', 'Arma2 MySQL') }}
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset class="arma2-mysql-answer">
                            {{ Form::label('databaseip', 'Database IP') }}
                            {{ Form::text('databaseip', $user->arma2_mysql_ip, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            {{ Form::label('database', 'Database') }}
                            {{ Form::text('database', $user->arma2_mysql_database, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            {{ Form::label('databaseusername', 'Database Username') }}
                            {{ Form::text('databaseusername', $user->arma2_mysql_username, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                            {{ Form::label('databasepassword', 'Database Password') }}
                            {{ Form::password('databasepassword', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                        </fieldset>
                {{ Form::close() }}
```

and the following script:

```
function valueChanged() {
if ($('.arma2-mysql').is(':checked')) {
    $(".arma2-mysql-answer").hide();
} else {
    $(".arma2-mysql-answer").show();
} 
}
```

This works fine when unchecking, but when checking again this doesn't show the form?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have more than one `.arma2-mysql` element?

Comment: Thanks! Alough it never answered my question it pointed me to the problem. I need to be fiding an element #arma2-mysql no .arma2-mysql!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class selector:

```
$('.arma2-mysql')
```

It looks like it should be an ID selector based on your html:

```
$('#arma2-mysql')
```

You also might consider using the  [Jquery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/%20Jquery%20Toggle) call to show/hide and you can dispense with the if statement all together.

Answer (score 2):

Try using toggle:

```
$('.arma2-mysql').change(function(){
$('.arma2-mysql-answer').toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/100/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
        $('.shownDiv').toggle();
    });
});

<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" /> Show div
<br/><br/>
<div class="shownDiv" style="display:none;">Shown when checked</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,

The issue was I was searching for the class `.arma2-mysql` when my element never had this class, instead it has an ID `#arma2-mysql`